# SQL Server: Creating a view and populating the columns with independent values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a view because I need it to populate based on someone else entering values into a separate table.

I have several columns I need but none of them have anything to do with each other. For example:

The first will produce:

```
a 
b 
c
```

And the second produces something like:

```
d 
e 
f 
g
```

And I would like the view to populate with the two columns side by side and if there are nulls (as is this case) they just show up as null on the bottom.

Am I thinking about this backwards? Does someone have a different design that could help me? Each different row is a different SQL query. Perhaps an idea with joins?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? mysql and sql server are NOT the same thing.

Comment: SQL Server @SeanLange. It added the suggestions for some reason. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` and `full outer join`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from (select col1, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select col2, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

This assumes that when you say "I have several columns I need but none of them have anything to do with each other", you really mean that you have columns in some other table.  This puts them in an arbitrary order.  If you have a particular order in mind for each column, the specify that in the `order by` columns.